# Scope issue with multiple directives on same page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that is used multiple times on the same page. The documentation has lead me to the following code:

```
<my-directive info="one"></my-directive>
<my-directive info="two"></my-directive>

.directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
      itemInfo: '=info'
     },
     templateUrl: 'my_directive.html'
   };
});
```

my_directive.html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemInfo.items">
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
    <div>{{item.value}}</div>
</div>
```

I can't get it to work, and I suspect it has to do with how I specify the scope in my directive and try to apply it in the ng-repeat. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you add a plunker?

Comment: Is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvh3V/) working the way you expect?  Can you show how you have `one` and `two` declared?